# How do I put text below an icon?

Tags: html, css

I want to put text directly below each icon like a caption. I'm not really sure what feature to use. I tried using span and display block but the text ends up somewhere weird and the icon shifts. I'm going to insert a small block of text under each, including the titles like "ABOUT". Also, I haven't put the pictures inside the css icon background yet.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-size: 13;
}

h1,h2,h3{margin: auto; text-align:center;}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 108px;
  background-color: #001e22;
}

header .wrap > img {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

li {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 48px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner > img {
width: 100%;
}

.wrap .block-row {
background: white;

}

.wrap #block1{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block2{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;

}

.wrap #block3{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block4{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}


h1{margin-top:80px; font-size:48px;}

.block-row .wrap #block1 span{display:block;}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SOFTWARE USED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="banner">
  <img src="building.png" alt="banner">
</section>

<h1>SOME ICONS</h1>
<section class="block-row">

<div class="wrap">
<div id="block1"><span> ABOUT </span></div>
<div id="block2"> </div>
<div id="block3"> </div>
<div id="block4"> </div>
</div>

</section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `:after` if you like to use other way and update `.block-row .wrap #block1 span{display:block;}` like below

codepen link https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/MZWeWL

```
  .block-row .wrap #block1:after{
  content:'hello world';
  display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    top: 100%;
}
.block-row .wrap #block2:after{
  content:'hello world2';
  display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    top: 100%;
}
.block-row .wrap #block3:after{
  content:'hello world3';
  display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    top: 100%;
}
.block-row .wrap #block4:after{
  content:'hello world4';
  display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    top: 100%;
}
```

and then your html just update this section

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div id="block1"> </div>
   <div id="block2"> </div>
   <div id="block3"> </div>
   <div id="block4"> </div>
</div>
```

Out put like this 
[image]

Comment: i meant i wanted the text below the icon

Comment: @wafflewafflewaffle I update my Answer Please check, I found that issue was with position `position` that should be Relative `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pseudo`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) as `:afetr` to each `#block` and in `content` set the text.

also see mark up to your code

```css
.wrap .block-row {
background: white;

}

.wrap .circle{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
position: relative;
}

.wrap .circle:after{
    content: 'ABOUT';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -18px;
    left: 24px;
}
.wrap #block2:after{
    content: 'SOME OTHER';
        bottom: -34px;
}
```

```html
<section class="block-row">

<div class="wrap">
<div id="block1" class="circle"></div>
<div id="block2" class="circle"> </div>
<div id="block3" class="circle"> </div>
<div id="block4" class="circle"> </div>
</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute for text span and relative for #block1,...2,3,4 parents position, with the "bottom" property of span, you can give the space between block and text:

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-size: 13;
}

h1,h2,h3{margin: auto; text-align:center;}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 108px;
  background-color: #001e22;
}

header .wrap > img {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

li {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 48px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner > img {
width: 100%;
}

.wrap .block-row {
background: white;

}

.wrap #block1{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block2{
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-top:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;

}

.wrap #block3{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block4{
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:80px;
margin-right:80px;
width:100px; 
height:100px;
background-color:#2fcbe0;
border-radius:100px;
display:inline-block;
}

.wrap #block1,
.wrap #block2,
.wrap #block3,
.wrap #block4 {
    position: relative;

    
}
.wrap #block1 span,
.wrap #block2 span,
.wrap #block3 span,
.wrap #block4 span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


h1{margin-top:80px; font-size:48px;}

.block-row .wrap #block1 span{display:block;}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SOFTWARE USED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="banner">
  <img src="building.png" alt="banner">
</section>

<h1>SOME ICONS</h1>
<section class="block-row">

<div class="wrap">
<div id="block1"><span> ABOUT </span></div>
<div id="block2"> <span> SOME TEXT </span></div>
<div id="block3"> <span> SOME TEXT </span></div>
<div id="block4"><span> SOME TEXT </span> </div>
</div>

</section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-size: 13;
}

h1,h2,h3{margin: auto; text-align:center;}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 108px;
  background-color: #001e22;
}

header .wrap > img {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

li {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 48px;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  .wrap #block1 {

    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #2fcbe0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrap #block2 {

    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #2fcbe0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrap #block3 {
    margin-top: 80px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #2fcbe0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.wrap #block4 {
    margin-top: 80px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #2fcbe0;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
} 
.main-block {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
 margin:0px 80px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SOFTWARE USED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="banner">
 <img src="building.png" alt="banner">
</section>

<h1>SOME ICONS</h1>
<section class="block-row">
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="main-block">
   <div id="block1"></div>
   <span> ABOUT </span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block">
   <div id="block2"></div>
   <span> ABOUT </span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block">
   <div id="block3"></div>
   <span> ABOUT </span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block">
   <div id="block4"></div>
   <span> ABOUT </span>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```